# MySql how can I send a message to all users PHP

Tags: mysql, arrays, messaging

So I'm trying to send a message to all the users in the database. I saw an other article but there it was used for emails and has commas between it. I don't know but maybe there is some solution for this to properly insert data with all the users ID.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $users[] = $row['ID']; 
}

$sendmes = "INSERT INTO notify (notfi, thumb_src, title, url, user_ID) VALUES ('$msg', '$src', '$title', '$url', '$users[]')";
```

This gives the Array(), but it seems not to work like this.
So I used

```
$user = implode(", ", $users);

$sendmes = "INSERT INTO notify (notfi, thumb_src, title, url, user_ID) VALUES ('$msg', '$src', '$title', '$url', '$user')";
```

After that it is still not working, this is because it uses commas between the IDs and only work for emails. After that I was searching google but couldn't find anything about it.

So my last hope is here and to help others with the same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"INSERT INTO notify (notfi, thumb_src, title, url, user_ID) VALUES ('$msg', '$src', '$title', '$url', '$users[]')"
```

- Here the value of the 'user_ID' should be a single user_id value, not an array.

You can check the following query:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $users[] = $row['ID']; 
}

foreach ($users as $user_id)
{
  $sendmes = "INSERT INTO notify (notfi, thumb_src, title, url, user_ID) VALUES ('$msg', '$src', '$title', '$url', '$user_id')";
  // Execute the Query;
}
```

Another approach can be:
Instead of single query for each user, if you want to insert them altogether, then you can change your query in the following way;

```
"INSERT INTO tbl_name (notfi, thumb_src, title, url, user_ID)
 VALUES
    ('$msg', '$src', '$title', '$url', '$users[0]'),
    ('$msg', '$src', '$title', '$url', '$users[1]'),
    ('$msg', '$src', '$title', '$url', '$users[2]')
    ....
    ('$msg', '$src', '$title', '$url', '$users[(count($users) - 1)]')"
```

But in this approach if the query becomes too large, or if there's any error in any of the insertion the remaining insertion will fail.

Comment: The first approach is the solution! Thank you so much. Now finally there is a solution for it on here!